# multiple desktops question on mac

Tags: desktop, mission-control

I have a question about multiple desktops. This function is super helpful since I only have a 13 inch macbook pro and my screen economy is vastly improved with multiple desktops since I am using ruby, sublime text, web browsing, and (due to my ADD) VLC and quicktime at the same time.

Questions:

1) How do I get multiple desktops to start at startup?

2) I have assigned web browsing to desktop 1 and ruby+sublime to desktop 2. How do I get these to open on these desktops permanently? Will 2 desktops be created if I open ruby and sublime after restarting my computer?

3) Is there a quick way to drag open applications between desktops?

4) Say I have VLC open on desktop 4 and I select that it opens on desktop 4. At startup, if I only have 1 desktop open, and I open VLC, will desktops 2 and 3 open? Are desktops reopened after restarting?

5) Any other useful tricks I should know about?

Comment: Only just found this question years later… Once created, Desktops are 'permanent'. They exist until you manually remove them. [This does not apply to fullscreen Spaces]. If you have an app assigned to Desktop 4 then 2 & 3 will just stay empty if nothing is assigned to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup your windows the way you like them.  When set right click on the application icon in the dock and go to **Options-->*Open at Login*** and ***This Desktop***.  This will open that application on that desktop at login.  I have found that some applications just don't work properly but most that I've tested work as expected and open to that desktop at login or when opened.

[image]

Comment: If VLC is on desktop 4 and on startup, if there's only 1 desktop open, will VLC open on desktop 4? Will desktop 2 and 3 just auto open if I open VLC?

Comment: In my experience, I can't speak for all apps, but it will open all four desktops and the app will be placed on the next available empty desktop.  So if you set VLC for Desktop 4 it will open 4 desktops but place VLC on Desktop 2.